# Django TinyMce was installed but is not working

Tags: django, tinymce

I've installed django-tinymce and it works on my pc very well. But when I pushed to github, and downloaded to my Mac. When I want to run server it shows error as following:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tinymce'
```

Comment: and then when I try to ```pip install django-tinymce``` it says:

```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

Comment: You should use `pip3 install django-tinymce` on mac.

Comment: I've already tried, @PedramParsian, it shows:

```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

Comment: Also try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1039641/866363) to see if that works for you?

Comment: But it just helped me to install tiny-mce again, when I try to run server it says again:

```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tinymce'
```

Comment: Are you using venv?

Comment: yes, man @PedramParsian

Comment: So if you run `pip3 install django-tinymce` **with your venv activated**, it should be ok.

Comment: @PedramParsian for sure, that code works well and result says ```Requirement already satisfied: django-tinymce ```. The problem is in ```python3 manage.py runserver```